# Jersey JAX-RS Maven Dependency causing deployment ERROR on Glassfish

Tags: jaxb, glassfish, jersey, eclipselink, jax-rs

I am trying to deploy a JAX-RS based webapp using Jersey and Glassfish 4.0 Server.

JAX-RS related configuration.
Application Event Listener:

```
public class ABCAppExceptionListener implements ApplicationEventListener {

    @Override
    public void onEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {}

    @Override
    public RequestEventListener onRequest(RequestEvent requestEvent) {
        return new ExceptionRequestEventListener();
    }

    public static class ExceptionRequestEventListener implements RequestEventListener{
        private final Logger logger;

        public ExceptionRequestEventListener(){
            logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(RequestEvent event) {
            switch (event.getType()){
                case ON_EXCEPTION:
                    Throwable t = event.getException();
                    logger.log(Level.ALL, "Found exception for requestType: "+event.getType(), t);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Registering Listener on Application:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class ABCApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(UserService.class);
        classes.add(ABCExceptionListener.class);
        return classes;
    }
```

maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Whenever I try to deploy my app with the maven dependency above I get a deployment ERROR:

---

**[ERROR] remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [IterableProvider>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 2 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer(@Named ClassAnalyzer, IterableProvider>)]. Please see server.log for more details.**

---

Comment: And what is your GF version?

Comment: Try to make the scope of your Jersey dependency provided. The thing is GF has Jersey libs pre-installed and you are trying to use different version of a single part of it.

Comment: I did that, it builds and deploys with success, but at runtime I get this: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.monitoring.ApplicationEventListener

Comment: That's because GF v4.0 has Jersey v2.0 which pre installed does not have ApplicationEventListener class. If you really need this functionality, you might want to trydeploying your application with all Jersey libs you going to use(in this case you should NOT set the scope as provided) and tell GF to use the libs bundled in the application archive. You should use GF specific deployment description to achieve this setting delegate="false".  You can find more info here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/gfqpi.html (more in the subsequent comment)

Comment: I have not found the relevan documentation for GF4, but I think they did not change it. Once you pack all the Jersey libs in your application archive file and make classloader use those libraries, it should work.